# How to setcookie on wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have problem with seting and reading cookie on wordpress site.

Here is what I'm doing:

1.Sending over js id to php

**ajax.js**

```
jQuery.post("/wp-content/themes/mytheme/ajax.php", {post_id: post_id}, function(data){

});
```

**ajax.php**

```
setcookie('myids', $_COOKIE['myids'].$_POST['post_id'], time()+3600*24*100, '/');
```

2.When I read that cookie ( echo $_COOKIE['myids']; )in /wp-content/themes/mytheme/**index.php**

I get value which I set and that is ok but when i try to read that cookie in /wp-content/themes/mytheme/ajax.php I am not getting cookie.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't posted what you are doing (codewise) to read the cookie, so we couldn't begin to say what you are doing _wrong_.

Comment: What is the contents of `$_COOKIE` as seen by /wp-content/themes/mytheme/ajax.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: put ajax.php in root ( /ajax.php ) and then it works.